# HTML forms - enabling browers to ask for remembering the value of a text form?

Tags: html, forms, browser, passwordbox

I have a field that I've labeled 'password', and I'd like the browser to ask the user whether they want to store that password. How do I do this? Is there an HTML attribute to use?

For instance the HTML for the form would be:

```
<form action="" method="POST" name="form">
Enter password:
<input type="text" name="password" /><br />
A checkbox
<input type="checkbox" name="some_checkbox" value="Yes" /><br />
A textarea<br />
<textarea name="input_text" cols=40 rows=10></textarea><br />
<input type=submit value="Submit">
```

And I'd like the browser to prompt for storing the 'password' input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it:

```
<input type="password" name="password" />
```

Note the proper `type` for the password box.

Answer (score 3):

You can't *explicitly* force the browser to show that dialog, but using the correct elements gives the browser a helping hint.

So make sure your password element has the `type="password"` attribute.

Comment: Thank you :) I chose the other one as the answer only because I was pretty dumb, and was using both type="text" and type="password" since I just added the latter to my existing code. I was confused as to what I was doing wrong until I read the other answer. However I wanted to let you know that I appreciate your answer as well, and I voted it up.